# Color Reference Only Available on macOS error Xcode 10

Tags: xcode, xcode10

I'm using color sets in my app inorder to make it easier to organize the colors for different views, but when I go to compile I get the error "Color references are only available on macOS", but I haven't got the error till now.

I tried cleaning the build folder, and restarting xcode, but it doesn't do anything, the error still keeps showing up. What can I do?

**anwser:**
I was able to solve the problem by not using any of the Mac default colors in the color selection. I had to use rgb to select the color in the asset folder.

Comment: In the assets folder you can add a color set, and depending on what you have set there can be different colors for different devices or on iOS 13 light and dark mode.

Comment: And you are building for a simulator?

Comment: No I’m trying to archive to upload to test flight

Comment: So you can build and run to simulator and device, but you cannot archive?

Comment: Thanks Matt but I solved it!

Comment: Cool. What was the solution? You should give it as an answer to your own question (do not include it in the question).

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: Right but don't use an edit to the question as an answer. Actually answer your own question.

Comment: Ok. In the future I will not.

Comment: But please change it for this question. That way we get your question along with your right answer, and that is how we help others in the future.

Comment: Please edit for the message is just a Warning not an Error.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing the answer in the original question, you can get around this issue by avoiding using any Mac system colors. You'll see any Color sets that do use system colors will be grayed out.
[image]

Click on the color squares and press Delete. Then fill in the equivalent hex codes or RGB, and it should work!

[image]